# Hide the presence of a key in a key-value storage

Tags: secure-storage

Problem: I want to build a key-value storage in such a way that it would be impossible to detect a presence of a key in the storage by inspecting it. In other words, any read operation with any valid key always returns a valid-looking value, and without additional knowledge about value it is impossible to say if this key was ever written to the storage, or is it a plain garbage.

Such kind of storage is possible. For example, a simple (but space consuming) approach would be to create a storage and pre-fill all possible valid keys with random values. Write operation replaces the existing value with the new one, delete operation replaces the existing value with a random one. Then just by looking at the storage it is impossible to tell which keys actually contain written values, and which just store a random garbage.
But this of course is impractical for large enough key space.

I suspect that there could be a more practical solution.

Comment: How would an authorized reader know whether or not they're using a valid key?

Comment: In my use case the authorized readers also have an oracle that can tell validity of the returned value.
To give more practical example of this oracle: the value stored in this special oblivious key-value storage actually is an index in another bigger storage to which only authorized actors have access (cloud database). So when an authorized reader reads the value from this special oblivious key-value storage, it then can query the cloud database using the retrieved value as an index in the cloud database.This construct prevents the untrusted cloud provider from learning the list of valid keys

Comment: Also (with some additional effort) it can even prevent the untrusted cloud provider from probing the storage to test if a guessed key is valid or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have a set of key-value pairs $(k_1, v_1), (k_2,v_2), \ldots$. You can store the coefficients of a polynomial $P$ that satisfies $P(k_i)=v_i$. The polynomial can be evaluated at any point to give a plausible output.

The degree of the polynomial leaks the number of key-value pairs, but if the $v_i$'s are uniform then the polynomial leaks nothing about the $k_i$'s. This is because for every way of fixing distinct $k_i$'s, the polynomial's coefficients are an invertible linear function of the $v_i$'s, so the coefficients are uniform if the $v_i$'s are uniform.

The only real downside is that polynomial evaluation is a bit slow: if there are $n$ key-value pairs then probing this data structure costs $\Theta(n)$.
However, there are alternatives to polynomials that have the security properties you need, with cheaper $O(\kappa)$ access time (for security parameter $\kappa$).
They have slightly higher storage overhead, whereas polynomials are optimal in size (exactly $n$ space to store $n$ key-value pairs).
The best reference for these data structures is actually an upcoming paper of mine, which will be on eprint in the next few weeks. I can post an update here when it's available.
In the meantime, the "best" publicly available *oblivious key-value store* is the probe-and-XOR-of-strings data structure that we propose in [ia.cr/2020/193](https://ia.cr/2020/193).
It has $O(\kappa)$ access time and $\sim 2.5n$ size to store $n$ key-value pairs.

Comment: Thank you @Mikero! Oblivious data store - that's what I am looking for! Also both PaXoS and polynomial approaches are looking very promising.
On a side note, do you think it makes sense to add an #oblivious-data-store tag? I used #secure-storage only because I was not able to find a better match. If you agree, could you please add it? Then I will re-tag my question with it.

Comment: Also I am quite interested in that future paper of yours, because I don't see atm how we can write a new key-value pair to the "polynomial" storage without a full knowledge of all existing keys.

Comment: When I say $O(\kappa)$ access time, I am referring to a single *read* from the data structure. There is no shortcut for *writes* in any of these constructions -- you need all of the key-value pairs and just regenerate the entire data structure.

Comment: I see.
What do you think, is it theoretically possible to create such an oblivious key-value store that allows for writes without the knowledge of the previously stored keys and which is less memory consuming than the trivial example from the main question?
I am ready to trade performance here for storage space.

Comment: What you are asking for seems very difficult. In all of the constructions I know about, we lookup a key $k$ by probing some positions in the data structure (the positions depend only on $k$) and adding the values at those positions. To update a key, we must modify at least one of these positions. But we must know which positions can be modified without affecting other key-value mappings. But this information inherently leaks information about the keys! -- I know that the key-value store holds no key that wants to probe this particular location. A completely new approach would be needed.